# How to choose a column layout in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm new to magento and trying to get my head around how to install the templates and its really starting to get frustrating, with the majority of google resources pointing the older versions, **I'm using 1.5.1 CE**

Basically I need know what are the required parts to set the layout, I've created a 1column.phtml in the template/page directory and am trying to get it to show up on the site. I've modified the page.xml file by copying one of the other column definitions and changed the appropriate parts and then gone into the administration->config->design section and put the name 1column and page_one_column in the template box but nothing seems to trigger it and it keeps looking back in the base directory for a 2 column layout. I'm using the "show template paths" to see this.

If someone could just list the required steps to be able to change a template assuming I have a modified layout/pages.xml and template/page/1column.phtml, that would be great, I get the feeling I'm doing something right but its just not working

Comment: paste in your layout file with relevant part that you have modified and you have better luck with answers. I know that we all have imagination but it's rather hard to imagine or assume how you write your xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need all your pages to be 1column.phtml then

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/1column.phtml">
```